# Cannot convert value of type '(CalculatorBrain) -> (Double) -> Double' to expected argument type '(Double) -> Double'

Tags: swift, type-conversion

```
struct CalculatorBrain {
    private var accumulator: Double?
    func changeSign(operand: Double) -> Double {
        return -operand
    }

    private enum Operation {
        case constant(Double)
        case unaryOperation((Double) -> Double)
    }
    private var operations: Dictionary<String,Operation> = [
        "π" : Operation.constant(Double.pi),
        "√" : Operation.unaryOperation(sqrt),
        "±" : Operation.unaryOperation(changeSign) /* Cannot convert value of type '(CalculatorBrain) -> (Double) -> Double' to expected argument type '(Double) -> Double'  */
    ]
}
```

---

I am getting the error message on the line starting with "±".
I looked up a solution online and here are the similar questions & potential solutions I found below. But I don't quite understand what's going on. Can anyone help?

[Similar Question + solution (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018923/swift-generics-error-cannot-convert-value-of-type-typet-to-expected-argumen)

[Similar Question + Solution (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201515/cannot-convert-value-of-type-avaudioplayer-type-to-expected-argument-type)

Comment: Use the preview to make sure your code is correctly formatted before clicking save.

Answer (score 2):

The `changeSign` function is an instance function of `CalculatorBrain`.

In Swift, any function bound to an instance of an object actually has the type `(Type) -> (Arguments) -> ReturnType`, instead of just `(Arguments) -> ReturnType`.

If you're writing code like `instance.doStuff(arguments)`, what is actually happening in the background is a partial application `Type.doStuff(instance)(arguments)`. `Type.doStuff(instance)` returns your instance function that you then can call using its normal arguments.

As you are creating the operations dictionary directly within the struct and not within a function or initializer of it, Swift only has access to static members of your type so instead of `changeSign` being bound to an instance of `CalculatorBrain`, you are getting the unbound `CalculatorBrain.changeSign` method.

That is why your function shows up as `(CalculatorBrain) -> (Double) -> Double` instead of just `(Double) -> Double`.

To fix this, make the method static, so it removes the partial application with an instance of `CalculatorBrain`, declare the function as a global function or define operations in an initializer of `CalculatorBrain` (though you might have trouble accessing instance members before finishing instantiation when using the last approach).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `changeSign` to `static`.

The non-static function will have an implicit "self" argument and thus not match the `(Double) -> Double` you are after.