# Swift Generics: Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<T>' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest<_>'

Tags: swift, generics, promise

I'm doing some refactoring to move code to using Promises (using Hydra) instead of async callbacks. I originally had this method and it worked fine:

```
static func fetch<D: AnyDTO, E: AnyEntity>(
    _ context      : NSManagedObjectContext, 
    fetch request  : NSFetchRequest<E>, 
    successHandler : @escaping ([D]) -> (), 
    errorHandler   : @escaping ErrorHandler)
```

So I changed this to work with promises like this:

```
import Hydra


static func fetch<D: AnyDTO, E: AnyEntity>(
    _ context     : NSManagedObjectContext, 
    fetch request : NSFetchRequest<E>) -> Promise<[D]> 
{
    return Promise<[D]>(in: .background) { resolve, reject, _ in
    ...
    }
}
```

with client code trying to call the function like this:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Location> = Location.fetchRequest()
return CacheUtils.fetch(context, fetch: request)
```

But the compiler is giving me this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest' to expected
>   argument type 'NSFetchRequest<_>'

and I'm unsure why. I've checked out similar questions, and noticed the issue of using a concrete type within the function (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018923/swift-generics-error-cannot-convert-value-of-type-typet-to-expected-argumen)). I think `Promise` might fit this bill, but on the other hand, the `Promise` is generic, so I'm not confident that is the problem. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to achieve in Swift?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746921/swift-cant-infer-generic-type-when-generic-type-is-being-passed-through-a-param) should help. Read the comments too. Specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746921/swift-cant-infer-generic-type-when-generic-type-is-being-passed-through-a-param#comment94348934_53747719) one. PS: Always share the link of 1-2 questions you've looked into. We don't know which one you did and which you didn't look into

Comment: Thx, reading now, and will edit w/ what I've checked out so far.